# Unable to create azure pipeline , it is getting stuck at Maven stage

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, mule

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>clx-salesforceupsert-ifa</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>mule-application</packaging>

    <name>clx-salesforceupsert-ifa</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

        <app.runtime>4.4.0-20220221</app.runtime>
        <mule.maven.plugin.version>3.5.4</mule.maven.plugin.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.mule.tools.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>mule-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${mule.maven.plugin.version}</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                <cloudHubDeployment>
                <uri>https://anypoint.mulesoft.com</uri>
                <server>${server}</server>
                <muleVersion>${app.runtime}</muleVersion>
                <applicationName>${app.name}</applicationName>
                <workers>${workers}</workers>
                <workerType>${workerType}</workerType>
                <environment>${environment}</environment>
                <objectStoreV2>true</objectStoreV2>
                
                </cloudHubDeployment>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.connectors</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-http-connector</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0</version>
            <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.connectors</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-sockets-connector</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
            <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>anypoint-exchange-v3</id>
            <name>Anypoint Exchange</name>
            <url>https://maven.anypoint.mulesoft.com/api/v3/maven</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>mulesoft-releases</id>
            <name>MuleSoft Releases Repository</name>
            <url>https://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>mulesoft-releases</id>
            <name>MuleSoft Releases Repository</name>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <url>https://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

I am creating an Azure pipeline, but at the maven stage it got stucked. This is the error i am getting while running the pipeline

> [ERROR] No goals have been specified for this build. You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format : or :[:]:. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy. -> [Help 1]

Comment: Can you share snippet of your script?

Comment: added the pom.xml

Comment: I meant the deployment script from the pipeline, not the pom.xml

Comment: I gather from the follow up question that the answer was useful. Please accept it as valid.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in the pom. You are not telling in the pipeline configuration which of the Maven goals to execute. For example package or deploy. The error is clearly stating that.

[Azure Maven task documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/maven?view=azure-devops) says the build will fail if goals is set to blank.